# Help needed - Approximating functions with geometric integration and derivation

Tags: functions, approximation

I've somehow managed to approximate some functions using cheap tricks as geometrically derivating the function and then geometrically integrating an easier equivalent of the derivative (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799014/approximation-of-x-proof-needed) for an example).

However, the proof I finally got in the example above worked 'mathematically' because I managed to get rid of the $\text{o}(1/x^\left(whatever\right))$ in my approximation of $x!$ by using $\frac{\text{d ln}(x!)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d ln}(\Gamma (x+1))}{\text{d}x} = \psi (x+1)$.

Had I used $x!=u(x)+\text{o}((1/x^\left(whatever\right))$, I would have had to take into account the $\frac{\text{d ln}(\text{o}((1/x^\left(whatever\right)))}{\text{d}x}$, and I have absolutely no idea how to deal with that.

Therefore, I was wondering, when exactly can I use such a method to get approximation of functions ?

---

To sum it up my question is : When can we approximate a function by geometrically integrating an approximation of its geometric derivative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is about integrating an estimate, your example is about taking derivatives. There is usually no problem integrating an estimate, although cancellation may give a better estimate. In any case, I will discuss the problem described in the question regarding derivatives.

---

**Differentiating A Landau-style Estimate**

The problem you are having is because $o(\dots)$ estimates a size, but not a smoothness. If you want to estimate a derivative, you need to have some information on smoothness.

For example, if $f(x)=\dfrac1x$, then as $x\to\infty$,
$$
f(x)=O(1/x)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
f'(x)=O(1/x^2)\tag{2}
$$
However, if $g(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$, then as $x\to\infty$,
$$
g(x)=O(1/x)\tag{3}
$$
but
$$
g'(x)=O(x)\tag{4}
$$

---

Information, such as log-convexity, can help estimate derivatives. For example, since
$$
x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)\tag{5}
$$
we get, by taking the log of $(5)$,
$$
\log(x)+\log(\Gamma(x))=\log(\Gamma(x+1))\tag{6}
$$
knowing that $\Gamma(x)$ is log-convex lets us know that the derivative of $\log(\Gamma(x))$ is increasing. Since
$$
\hspace{-1cm}\small\log(x-1)=\frac{\log(\Gamma(x))-\log(\Gamma(x-1))}{x-(x-1)}\le\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(\Gamma(x))\le\frac{\log(\log(\Gamma(x+1))-\Gamma(x))}{(x+1)-x}=\log(x)\tag{7}
$$
we can determine $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(\Gamma(x))$ to within an error of $\log(x)-\log(x-1)\sim\frac1x$. That is,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(\Gamma(x))=\log(x)+O(1/x)\tag{8}
$$

---

**Integrating A Landau-style Estimate**

If $f(x)=O(g(x))$ (implying that $g(x)\gt0$), then
$$
\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=O\left(\int_0^xg(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\tag{9}
$$
However, we can often do better because of cancellation. For example, by integrating $\cos(x)=O(1)$, we get that $\sin(x)=O(x)$, which is true. However, cancellation between positive and negative parts of $\cos(x)$, we actually get that $\sin(x)=O(1)$.